# Limited result is coming when I run Join query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting **only 5001 rows** of result when I run this query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages
        WHEN 0
            THEN V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages + (V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages + ((V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages * 2) - (V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages)))
        ELSE V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages
    END AS PrintedPages,
    V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages AS BWPages,
    V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages AS ColorPages,
    CASE V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages
        WHEN 0
            THEN V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages + ((V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages * 2) - (V_ALL.JOB_qty_BWPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_ColorPages))
        ELSE V_ALL.JOB_qty_BlankPages
    END AS BlankPages,
    V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages AS SimplexPages,
    V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages * 2 AS DuplexPages,
    V_ALL.JOB_qty_SimplexPages + V_ALL.JOB_qty_DuplexPages AS TotalSheets,
    V_All.JOB_lab_NTDomainName,
    V_All.Lab_GroupName,
    V_All.JOB_lab_NTUserName
    ,V_All.Lab_NTFullUserName
    ,V_All.PRINTER_lab_Location
    ,V_All.JOB_lab_DocumentName
    ,V_All.JOB_qty_Size
    ,V_All.JOB_qty_Copies
    ,V_All.JOB_date_Submitted
    ,T_AD_Data.lab_sAMAccountName
    ,T_AD_Data.lab_department
    ,T_AD_Data.lab_physicalDeliveryOfficeName
FROM
    V_All
LEFT JOIN 
    T_AD_Data ON V_ALL.lab_NTFullUserName = T_AD_Data.lab_sAMAccountName
WHERE 
    JOB_date_Submitted BETWEEN '2015-01-01 12:59:59.000'
                       AND '2015-01-31 12:59:59.000';
```

Comment: You can use top function. Retrieve to top 50 rows

Comment: Give more details to your question. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Hi I need complete data available in tables as per the date given in query, i.e. 01st  Jan to 31st Jan, but I am getting only limited rows(5001 rows), i.e. 01st to 24th Jan. If I remove the WHERE function and run the query I am getting result is only 5001 rows in result table. Its not exceeding more than 5001 rows. Hope you got my question.

Comment: @sravankumar - How many rows does the table `V_All` have?

Comment: @sravankumar - Are you sure if there is actually any data between 24th Jan and 31st Jan?

Comment: Try the following queries: `SELECT COUNT(*) FORM V_ALL`, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_AD_DATA`, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V_ALL LEFT JOIN T_AD_Data ON V_ALL.lab_NTFullUserName = T_AD_Data.lab_sAMAccountName WHERE JOB_date_Submitted BETWEEN '2015-01-01 12:59:59.000' AND '2015-01-31 12:59:59.000';` and let us know what the results are for each query.

Comment: yes the data is available from Jan2015 to till date, when I excluding WHERE function I should get complete data from JAN to till date, but its not happing like that. its giving only first 5001 rows. Is their any settings need to be done to increase the result rows.?

Answer (score 0):

First check how many rows are there in each table and when u use a left join it will return all rows from the left table (V_All), with the matching rows in the right table (T_AD_Data).

So check whether you have any non matching rows between these tables. If there are then you need to change the join condition.